# Find out what object instance id I am colliding with

Tags: game-maker-studio-2

I am trying to figure out how I can tell what obj instance I am in collision with. An example of what I would want is:

if(place_meeting(x,y,exampleobj.instance_id)){do something}

The issue is that if there are to example obj, if I wanted a value from exmaple obj, I would get the first created example obj, but maybe not the one I am colliding with.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know what you've ran into, use `instance_place` rather than `place_meeting`, like so

```
var thing = instance_place(x, y, exampleobj);
if (thing != noone) {
    // you can now work with it, e.g. `thing.hp -= 1;`
}
```